# docker run with latest postgres alpine image

Tags: postgresql, docker

How can I specify using whatever the latest postgres-alpine image is when doing a `docker run`?

I can't hardcode a specific versioned image. I would assume there's some way to either natively specify "latest matching *-alpine" or some programmatic way to check the [available tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/postgres/tags/) and filter from there.

If it matters, this is running inside a bash script. The snippet's going to end up looking like

```
docker run -it POSTGRES-HERE pg_dump [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is alpine tag that gives the latest version.

postgres version in postgres:alpine is 10.5 which the latest as of today. 11 is in beta.